# Flutter 2.5 cannot recognise sdkmmnager, although everything was fine before upgrading

Tags: flutter

So yesterday i upgraded flutter to 2.5 and flutter doctor said android-licenses status unknown. So, I ran `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and it says that sdkmanager not found although the previous version which was probably 2.2.3 didn't say anything like that. I did not install cmdline-tools the "android studio" way. I followed a guide and downloaded the android cmdline-tools.zip file, unpacked it inside "android" folder, made a new tools folder (inside android folder) and copied everything from the android folder to the tools folder. Then I set path to sdkmanager, platform-tools and emulator.
After that I installed platform-tools 31.0.0, android-sdk 31.0.0 and an emulator. At that time flutter was able to recognise sdkmanager and it gave no errors. How do i solve this? Did something related to where the sdkmanager should be located change?

The output of flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on Arch Linux 5.13.13-zen1-1-zen, locale
    en_IN.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more
      details.
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

and the output of flutter doctor --android-licenses:

```
cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.
```

Also i can run the default app just fine.
I am running linux.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you can use this command:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="Path to your Android Studio"
```

Double check that inside Android Studio > SDK Manager > SDK Tools, Android SDK Command-line Tools are installed.

Comment: I did not install android-studio, I installed the command-line tools manually following this:- https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-setup-android-sdk-without-android-studio-6d60d0f2812a. Also, I am running linux (sorry, didnn't  mention  that :P)